# Python Regex to match a colon either side (left and right) of a word

Tags: python, regex, nlp

At a complete loss here - trying to match a a colon either side of any given word in a passage of text.

For example:

```
:wave: Hello guys! :partyface: another huge win for us all to celebrate!
```

An appropriate regex that would match:

```
:wave:
:partyface:
```

Really appreciate your help!

```
\w*:\b
```

Comment: What about just `:\w+:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch all the content

```
:[^:]*:
```

To catch the content between

```
(?<=:)[^:]*(?=:)
```

Comment: Note that using a negated character class like that, it could also just match only newlines in between, where my assumption is that the OP wants to match at least a single none whitespace character or only word characters. See  https://regex101.com/r/towFOb/1

Comment: You're right. It could be improved this way **(?<=:)[^:\r\n]*(?=:)** to avoid taking newlines.

Comment: All of these suggestions helped - thank you very much!